# IDEs that can embed gVim as editor

Tags: ide, vim

Are there any IDEs that can embed gvim as its editor? I found [PIDA](http://pida.co.uk) for linux, I'm wondering if there are any windows equivalent for this. I'm not looking for Vi emulation, I am looking for IDEs that can fully embed gVim (so I can use all the Vim plugins).

Comment: is a shame than embedding vim inside intellij was only a hackaton project, but this show than it is possible! https://github.com/JetBrains/hackathon-Embeditor

Comment: Although there are useful answers here (including my own for NetBeans), anybody thinking of this should ask themselves why they would want to embed Vim into an IDE. Native Vim + ctags + plugins + custom commands can easily replace any IDE and be far more powerful and responsive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other than PIDA the only one I know is [eclim](http://eclim.org/) which has a couple of modes (control eclipse from vim or embed vim inside eclipse window). I haven't tried it myself but it looks like it supports Windows...

You can find a more comprehensive discussion of this with lots of projects (past and present) [here](http://www.freehackers.org/VimIntegration).

Answer (score 4):

You can use it with Visual Studio:

[visual_studio.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=864)

Answer (score 2):

[ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/viemu-vi-vim-visual-studio.html) is an add-in for Visual Studio that provides a Vim environment in the editor. It is commercial and highly polished.

Comment: Do you know if it supports vim plugins?

Comment: It does not support vim plugins but you can have a limited vimrc file.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can run with vim embedded if you install [eclim](http://eclim.org/).

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans has support for **[jvi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/)**, which is a Java port of vim. For every day programming, I hardly notice any functional difference between jvi and vim (except sometimes ^W does not work in edit mode.)

Support for code completion, clickable function navigation, inline documentation, syntax highlighting, and other native Netbeans editor functionality is preserved. That is, jvi functionality does not remove native functionality, as I have experienced with other vim plugins that I have tried before.