# Emacs integrated with a different IDE

Tags: emacs, ide

I have seen several post comparing emacs as IDE with IDEs such as Eclipse.
Usually it is assumed that all activities will be done through the emacs facilities and facilities provided by command line tools.

How easy would it be to integrate an IDE such as Eclipse with emacs, emacs being either an editing component, or an interface to Eclipe's features?
Both projects are open-source and both support extensions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IDEs that can embed gVim as editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751777/ides-that-can-embed-gvim-as-editor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe emacs-eclim is an appropriate option for you. https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim.
Empowerd by eclim which import the Eclipse functionality to your editor, you can do what you want: emacs being either an editing component, or an interface to Eclipe's features.

Comment: I think at the moment it only supports java. On the bright side the source files are quite short, so it might be easy to implement missing features

Comment: Please check out http://eclim.org/ and read the document instead of "I think". "The initial goal was to provide Eclipse’s java functionality in vim, but support for various other languages (c/c++, php, python, ruby, css, html, xml, etc.) have been added and several more are planned."

Comment: I have read the documentation for the emacs subproject - the link you gave me. It's only java for emacs. Vim has more features. Before reading documentation make sure it's the right one

Comment: Well, it seems there is a misunderstanding between us: you said emacs-eclim while I said eclim. Sorry. Yes, if you use emacs-eclim then java is the only language supported. You have to implement some feature by yourself if you want to use other languages.